# Adding two peers in ethereum privatenet on same machine

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am trying to add two peers in ethereum privatenet but not adding its shows peer count is 0. I run the below commands

Node1:

```
geth --identity "Privatenet1" --datadir=./Privatenet1 --networkid 1995 --nodiscover --maxpeers=2 --mine --syncmode fast --port 30303 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" --nat "any"
```

Node2:

```
geth --identity "Privatenet2" --datadir=./Privatenet2 --networkid 1995 --nodiscover --maxpeers 2 --mine --syncmode fast --port 30305 --rpc --rpcport 8540 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" --nat "any"
```

my genesis.json file for both nodes is given bellow:

```
{
   "config": {
      "chainId": 1995,
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip158Block": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 0
   },
   "difficulty": "400",
   "gasLimit": "2000000",
   "alloc": {
      "a620c4ffe82b2d2a4f3a9efc9d8c88f960696464": { 
          "balance": "100000000000000000000000" 
      },
      "db93c17c1b206ad4925e72896888012ea56a6005": { 
          "balance": "120000000000000000000000" 
      }
   }
}
```

then I tried to add node2 peer in node1 as below:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://cb2b35bc613fb9e700a5884c0e1bcb4e69e908e1a4509999ba51646cc443743b21b3d5e5c4b9353351a20a4e27321ad310e0fdcc60f26b4e975f5f133707615c@127.0.0.1:30305?discport=0")
```

enode is validated and showing **true** but peer count is still **0** and admin.peers is **null**. I researched on it and I allowed all ports using **sudo ufw allow portnumber** and **telnet 127.0.0.1 30303** throwing Error like ***Connection closed by foreign host.***  is it firewall blocks my connection? can anyone please tell me the solution to resolve this issue.